# Is there an event that tells when the window is visible (painted, not black)?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, xul, xulrunner

My Xul app will run in a very slow system, and the ["active" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events#Window_activation_events) of the Xul windows is called while my window is still not visible (the window area is black waiting for the window to be painted). A second later the window is painted.

Is there an event that tells when the window is visible (painted, not black)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [MozAfterPaint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#MozAfterPaint) event will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Does window.`onload` work any better?

Comment: Not, this is the first event to occur. Later there's the onfocus, and the active. I need one after the active, when the window is really visible.

Comment: How are you setting the window black, CSS?

Comment: no, the are where the window will appear is black because the system is low, and a second later the window appear. I edited the question to clarify this part, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with the limitations of old hardware :)

If there is an image in your page, you could try adding `onload` to the image and see what happens...

If you are using a specific box, couldn't you use `window.setTimeout()`?